# React Native 0.44 PushNotifcationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification handles JavaScript Date objects in simulator, not on devices

Tags: javascript, date, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

react-native: 0.44.3

Target Platform: iOS

Development Operating System: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Build tools: XCode

This behavior results in a very confusing bug where scheduled notifications work as expected on the simulator, but fail in a very mysterious way on a device.

**To reproduce:**

Schedule a local notification for one minute in the future:

```js
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({ 
  fireDate: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), 
  alertBody: 'message'
});
```

Run this build in the simulator (by default this is a Debug build unless you mess with settings, I believe)

Observe that your notification gets scheduled as expected.

Run this build as a Debug build on your device through XCode (Edit your scheme so that Run uses Debug instead of Release)

Observe a crash when you attempt to schedule your notification

Run this as a Release build on your device.

Observe that the notification fires immediately (note that this is the expected iOS behavior if a scheduled notification is assigned a null date or a date that has already passed.)

Note that in order to observe the immediately-fired notification, you must have a listener set up to handle it and provide feedback. It seems that a local notification will not be displayed on iOS if its associated app is in the foreground (AppState: 'active').

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve this, convert your Date objects to Unix time. This example sets fireDate a minute into the future:

`let fireDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000).getTime();`

Date objects cannot be passed over the RCT bridge, and must be converted to a string or a number.

However, note that calling toString() on your Date object will also not work. Recommended solution is to use getTime() to get a Unix timestamp.